# Reading a decoded JSON Lua table

Tags: c++, json, lua

I'm learning Lua to use as a component in a piece of software I'm working on, and largely it's going to be parsing JSON files.

I'm parsing with http://regex.info/blog/lua/json, and I can `io.input` a file in and parse it with `JSON:decode(io.read("*all"))` into a `local lua_value` just fine; and subsequently `JSON:encode_pretty(lua_value)` to verify the JSON back out to the console.

I can pull the key of a simple top-level JSON value just fine;

```
{ "book":"LUA For Dummies int" }
```

where `print(JSON_file["book"])` will return `LUA For Dummies` as expected.

But when it comes to reading a nested key:

```
{ "book": [
    
    {"title":"LUA For Dummies"}

]
}
```

I can't tell from Lua documentation or the JSON parser's source code how nested values (here, `"title"`) get read in to the Lua table.
From naive `C++` intuition, I'm looking for something like a multidimensional array as in `print(JSON_file["book","title"])`.

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the returned value from `JSON:decode` is a sensible lua table then all you need is

```
print(JSON_file["book"][1]["title"])
```

which can be written nicer as

```
print(JSON_file.book[1].title)
```

And if you're coming from a C++ background - watch out - lua arrays are 1 based, rather than 0 based. (Can't count the number of times thats tripped me up.)

Comment: I get `nil` for both of those :/

Comment: `print(JSON_file.book)` returns a table address if that means anything. But appending `.title` returns `nil`.

Comment: @user2717676: Try `JSON_file["book"][1]["title"]`

Comment: Niccolo is spot on. I missed the nesting inside an array. Updating answer to be correct.